# What are the differences between rpm.org and rpm5.org?

Tags: rpm, homebrew

I would like to make a pull request for upgrading the [rpm formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/rpm.rb) of [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). And, I'm looking for the latest stable code base for rpm. I found two project: http://rpm.org and http://rpm5.org

The current rpm formula of Homebrew is based on version 5.4.15 from rpm5.org, published the 24 Aug. 2014. On rpm.org, there is a version 4.13.0.1 published the 16 Feb. 2017.

What are the differences between versions of rpm published on rpm5.org and those published on rpm.org?

Which one gives the latest stable code base for rpm?

Answer (score 0):

See the summary here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpm_(software)#Forks

and more verbose description of the fork here:
http://www.internetnews.com/dev-news/article.php/3720556/RPM+5+a+Fork+in+The+Linux+Packaging.htm

The summary is that big Linux companies use rpm.org and the code is actively maintained there.